# Is there a way to split/autoscale gzip source files in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm struggling with a pipeline template right now.
I don't have the same behavior when input file is gzipped or not.

Here are the worker logs for a csv file:

```
Splitting filepattern gs://bucket/file.csv into bundles of size 22369621 took 125 ms and produced 1 files and 128 bundles
Splitting source gs://bucket/file.csv into bundles of estimated size 22369621 bytes produced 128 bundles. Rebundling into 100 bundles.
Splitting source gs://bucket/file.csv produced 100 bundles with total serialized response size 187328
```

Then the source is correctly splitted and the job is getting autoscaled to whatever the proper number of workers is for the task.

Now here's the log for the exact same file, which is now gzipped:

```
Splitting filepattern gs://bucket/file.csv.gz into bundles of size 22369621 took 137 ms and produced 1 files and 1 bundles
Splitting source gs://bucket/file.csv.gz produced 1 bundles with total serialized response size 1925
```

And then these are popping, few seconds/minutes later once the data starts getting through:

```
Proposing dynamic split of work unit dev01-processing;2020-02-21_03_30_25-2364220079620552332;7684124696241385390 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5126594305038452}
Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source.
```

It seems it can't scale, maybe because the size of the file is not what is expected.

Here's the code:

```
ValueProvider<String> input = options.getInput();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
PCollection<String> csvLines = p.apply(TextIO.read().from(input)/*.withCompression(Compression.GZIP)*/);
...
```

I just have to remove the comments to build the template with "gzip input" version.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong which is preventing the job to autoscale with the gzip input?

Comment: Doing a bit of research, it seems GZIP is not splittable, so I might have to use BZ2 instead? http://comphadoop.weebly.com

Comment: well ... answering to myself: same behavior with BZ2 files

Answer (score 0):

Is is mentioned [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/CompressedSource.java#L361) that compressed sources are not splittable.